# how to delete a listview item as code below?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I just need to delete an item from this list, I already have the index that I want but can not find a way to delete.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();

// get all songs from sdcard
this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

// looping through playlist
for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    songsListData.add(song);
}

// Adding menuItems to ListView
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    songsListData,
    R.layout.playlist_item,
    new String[] { "songTitle" },
    new int[] { R.id.songTitle2 });

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the index, try these

`songsListData.remove(index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

maybe in onItemClick

Comment: My adapter has the option "notifyDataSetChanged()". :/

Comment: songsListData.remove(aux);
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged(); is work, now lacks only move the sdcard also

Comment: String selectedFilePath = songsList2.get(aux).get("songPath");
    File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
    file.delete(); now Yes!!!:D

Answer (score 0):

First remove item from your songsListData Collection and reload the list view.